# How to write "Thank you" at the end of the page in multi-choice questions?

Tags: exam

In previous question three days ago [How to write "End" and "Thank you very much" at the end of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453418/how-to-write-end-and-thank-you-very-much-at-the-end-of-the-page/453426?noredirect=1#comment1140329_453426), I just want to put at the end of the page. However, I have tested with the other template and can not put the text "Thank you" at the end of the page. 
How can I do that? Thanks a lot

My code is here:

The contain of test_exam.tex file is here

```
\usepackage{exam} 
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.0cm, bmargin=1.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\ContinuousNumbering 
\ShortKey
\NumberOfVersions{1}  
\SectionPrefix{\relax }
\madethi{111}
\tieudetracnghiem
\tieudedapan
\tieudeduoi
\daungoac{}{.}
\chucauhoi{Question} 
\mauchu{black}
\sotrang{4}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.125}
\NoRearrange
```

The exam.sty file is here

```
\ProvidesPackage{exam}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\parskip=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@scau{\ }
\newcounter{madetracnghiem}
\newcommand{\madethi}[1]{\setcounter{madetracnghiem}{#1}
\addtocounter{madetracnghiem}{-1}}
\newcommand{\socauhoi}[1]{\renewcommand{\@scau}{ #1}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\Fullpages}{\setlength{\topmargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
                        \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
                        \setlength{\textwidth}{17truecm}
                        \setlength{\textheight}{25truecm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1cm}
}
\makeatletter
\def\tieudetracnghiem{
\begin{examtop}
\stepcounter{madetracnghiem}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
\centering
{\bf \@tkythi}\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{\bf  \@tmonhoc}\qquad\qquad\qquad \textbf{\fbox{Code \themadetracnghiem}}\\ \bigskip 
{\it \@tgian}\\
\end{minipage}

\end{examtop}
}

% 
\def\tieudedapan{
\begin{keytop}
\@@line{\fbox{Code \themadetracnghiem}\hfill{\bf\Large ANSWER}\hfill}
\end{keytop}
}
\def\@strang{ }
\newcommand{\sotrang}[1]{\renewcommand{\@strang}{#1}}
\def\tieudeduoi{
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
 \vspace*{-18pt}%
{\hfill {\it  Page\ \thepage/\@strang - Code \themadetracnghiem}}
}%
}}

\newcommand{\chucauhoi}[1]{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textcolor{\@mauchu}{\bf #1\ \theenumi.}}}
\newcommand{\mauchu}[1]{\renewcommand{\@mauchu}{#1}}
\newcommand{\daungoac}[2]{\renewcommand{\@leftdot}{#1}\renewcommand{\@rightdot}{#2}}
\newcommand{\chuphuongan}[1]{\renewcommand{\@upletter}{#1}} 


\setlength{\labelwidth}{48truept}
\newcommand{\bonpa}[4]{
\examvspace*{-0.6\baselineskip}
\word{{#1}{#4}{#1}{#1}{#4}{#1}{#1}{#2}{#4}{#2}{#2}{#4}{#2}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#3}{#3}{#4}{#3}{#3}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\word{{#2}{#1}{#4}{#3}{#1}{#4}{#3}{#1}{#2}{#4}{#3}{#2}{#4}{#3}{#1}{#3}{#4}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#2}{#2}{#1}{#1}}
\word{{#3}{#2}{#2}{#2}{#3}{#3}{#4}{#3}{#1}{#1}{#1}{#3}{#3}{#4}{#2}{#1}{#1}{#1}{#2}{#2}{#4}{#4}{#4}{#4}}
\word{{#4}{#3}{#3}{#4}{#2}{#2}{#2}{#4}{#3}{#3}{#4}{#1}{#1}{#1}{#4}{#2}{#2}{#4}{#1}{#1}{#1}{#3}{#3}{#2}}
}

\def\@datcotphai{ }
\def\@datcottrai{\examhspace*{-12pt}}

\newcommand{\datcot}[1][0]{\ifthenelse{#1=0}{
\renewcommand{\@datcotphai}{ }
}{
\renewcommand{\@datcotphai}{\parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}}
}}

\newcommand{\sai}[1]{\choice{\@datcotphai{#1\@datcottrai}}}
\newcommand{\dung}[1]{\choice[!]{\@datcotphai{#1\@datcottrai}}}
\newcommand{\false}[1]{\choice{#1}}
\newcommand{\true}[1]{\choice[!]{#1}}
\newcommand{\liencau}{\renewcommand{\@tachcau}{\examvspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}}}
\newcommand{\motcot}[1]{\parbox[t]{\shortitemwidth}{#1\strut}}
\newcommand{\haicot}[1]{\parbox[t]{2\shortitemwidth}{#1\strut}}
\newcommand{\bacot}[1]{\parbox[t]{3\shortitemwidth}{#1\strut}}
\newcommand{\boncot}[1]{\parbox[t]{4.4\shortitemwidth}{#1}}
\makeatother

\abovedisplayskip=0pt plus 0pt minus 3pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 0pt minus 3pt
\belowdisplayskip=\abovedisplayskip
\belowdisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayshortskip
\setlength{\afterinstsep}{0truept}
\setlength{\aftersectsep}{0truept}
\setlength{\beforeinstsep}{0truept}
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{3.5truecm}
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{0truept}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pc}
\def\ktrang{\makebox[1.5cm]{\hrulefill}}
\hfuzz=1pt
\sloppy
```

And the main.text file is here

```
\input{test_exam.tex}
\begin{document}

\begin{vnmultiplechoice}[ rearrange=yes, keycolumns=5]%

\begin{question}  % question 1
    Determine whether or not each of the following signal is periodic $x[n] = cos(\frac{\pi n^{2}}{8})$. If a signal is periodic, determine its fundamental period.
    \datcot
    \bonpa
    {\false{$0$.}}
    {\false{$T = 4$.}}
    {\false{$T = 6$.}}
    {\true{$T = 8$.}}
\end{question}

\begin{question}  % question 2
    Find T of the discrete signal $x[n] = cos(\pi n^{2})$?
    \datcot
    \bonpa
    {\false{$T = 0$.}}
    {\false{$T = 4$.}}
    {\true{$T = 6$.}}
    {\false{$T = 8$.}}
\end{question}
\end{vnmultiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The template as below

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqxclcd8j28sfxv/AADq8McA9LjVqHWMItLbjpCua?dl=0

Comment: on which page? on the last (of the multi page document), or on the each? please elaborate.

Comment: @Zarko on the last page (of the multi page document)

Comment: but for this you got (and accept) answer on your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453418/how-to-write-end-and-thank-you-very-much-at-the-end-of-the-page/453426?noredirect=1#comment1140329_453426).

Comment: @Zarko in the previous question, the text is hide on the last page (answer page), but I just want to put it on the last page (question page). You can see at here https://www.overleaf.com/project/5bb80cbf5ee0fb32b449b691

Comment: sorry, i not use overleaf, so i cant see your document. please provide in question a complete small document with dummy text, from which we can see, what you like to achieve.

Comment: answer on your questions are not only for you but for anyone with similar problems. that they can understand you problem, they need more complete question, which they can test it. i doubt that in overleaf will be your document accessible after some years.

Comment: @Zarko the text in latex is too long, I can not copy all of them and paste it in my question. You can see at here. 

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqxclcd8j28sfxv/AADq8McA9LjVqHWMItLbjpCua?dl=0

Comment: make it shorter as i do in my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84111/discussion-between-user3727281-and-zarko).

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**

after discussion in chat room i recognize that document style `examdesign` which you use, all specific environments (questions, vnmultiplechoice) treat as floats and consequently all added text is pushed to the first page. therefore simple solution, which work with `article` and other standard document classes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                   % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\vfill\centerline{\Large Thank you}
\clearpage

\textbf{here follows answers}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text areas borders)

**doesn't work** with `examendesign`. shortly, your demand so far **is not possible** to achieve with this document class.

it my be worth to write to the package author for some advice or send to him a feature request.

Comment: I cant still apply your suggestion to it.